# creating wifi hotspot but internet is not accessible

Tags: 14.04

I created wifi hotspot on ubuntu 14.04,it got created but i can not access Internet.
wifi is getting connect.Internet connection is DSL connetction.

Answer (score 0):

Open network connections, choose your wifi network, choose edit.

Under IPv4 settings from the method list choose **shared to other computers**.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because the hotspot does not auto allocate IP address via DHCP to the mobile phone. From the phone you will see that no IP traffic etc.

Comment: I got  the Internet access but after 1 minute or less then this it is not accessible i have to restart the hotsopt to access the Internet